# Visual Code IntelliSense between Angular template and component

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, intellisense, angular5

I switched to Visual Code recently and trying to solve tiny but important issue.
Assume you have template

```
  <div class="educationYears">
        <ng-select class="select ngFilter"
                   [options]="eduYearOptions$ | async"
                   (selected) = "onSelectedYear($event)"
                   placeholder= "2017-2018"
                   notFoundMsg=""
        ></ng-select>
      </div>
```

and in component

```
 eduYearOptions$: Observable<IOption[]>;
```

The issue is when typing eduYearOptions$ in template Visual Code does not autoComplete it( does not provide suggestions). Installed Angular Language Service and it does not help. Could you please suggest plugins or ways to solve it?
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try [angular2-inline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=natewallace.angular2-inline) great plugin for code completion, highlighting, and hover information for inline html template

Comment: I am using that.But it is not for that purpose.